# Get all text between bracket but skip nested bracket Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to get all text that is in brackets "test_two".

```
String test = "
    test_one{
     My Text One
    }
    test_two{
     My Text Two
       sub_test_one{
         My Sub Text
        }
       sub_test_two{
         My Sub Text
        }
    }
    test_three{
     My Text Three
    }"
```

My Code:

```
        int testOne = test.indexOf("test_two");
        int startTestOne = test.indexOf('{', testOne);
        int endTestOne = test.indexOf('}', testOne);
        String test3_2 = test.substring(startTestOne + 2, endTestOne);
```

which gives me, but i want whole text from "test_two" brackets

```
My Text Two
       sub_test{
         My Sub Text
```

Comment: Do you need the brackets to match or just get everything in between the first opening and the last closing bracket? If the first, use a proper parser to get the matches. Just String operations won't help much. If the latter it would be easier: `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` should be sufficient along with a few checks (e.g. that first <= last)

Comment: I need to get all text only from "test_two" including brackets inside excluding test_one, test_three

Comment: Regular expressions cannot handle this kind of recursive thing, by definition [Chomsky 1956]. You're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @user207421 can you help find solution?

Comment: Not if you insist on using regular expressions. Once you get over that mind-block, the solution is trivial, and several useful suggestions towards it have already been given here. And if you don't want regular expressions why the [tag:regex] tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text between the curly brackets that start immediately after the target label (`test_two`) we can iterate over the given string and maintain `StringBuilder`, which would eventually contain the result, and a stack of brackets represented as a `Deque`.

When the brackets are balanced, i.e. the stack is empty, and we're not at the first opening curly after `test_two`, we're done.

```
String test = """
    test_one{
     My Text One
    }
    test_two{
     My Text Two
       sub_test_one{
         My Sub Text
        }
       sub_test_two{
         My Sub Text
        }
    }
    test_three{
     My Text Three
    }""";

int target = test.indexOf("test_two");
int firstOpeningCurly = test.indexOf('{', target);
        
StringBuilder testTwoText = new StringBuilder();
Deque<Character> brackets = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
for (int i = firstOpeningCurly; i < test.length(); i++) {
    char next = test.charAt(i);
            
    if (next == '{') brackets.push('{');
    if (i == firstOpeningCurly) continue;
            
    if (next == '}') brackets.pop();
            
    if (i != firstOpeningCurly && brackets.isEmpty()) break;
            
    testTwoText.append(next);
}
    
System.out.println(testTwoText);
```

*Output:*

```
 My Text Two
   sub_test_one{
     My Sub Text
    }
   sub_test_two{
     My Sub Text
    }
```

Comment: I need to get all text only from "test_two" including brackets inside excluding test_one, test_three

Comment: @Влад You always expect the input to have such a structure `"test_one{...}test_two{...}test_three{...}"`? And `test_one`, `test_three` are not expected to have nested curly brackets?

Comment: Brackets will be everywhere, I need to get all the text that is under the brackets in "test_two", any method

Comment: @Влад Got it, done - updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting means, that there's an opening brace before the closing brace. We can make use of this property to ignore all nested elements.

```
String test = """
    test_one{
     My Text One
    }
    test_two{
     My Text Two
       sub_test_one{
         My Sub Text
        }
       sub_test_two{
         My Sub Text
        }
    }
    test_three{
     My Text Three
    }""";

String testTwoLabel = "test_two";
int startOfTestTwoLabel = test.indexOf(testTwoLabel);
int startOfTestTwo = test.indexOf("{", startOfTestTwoLabel);

int nextClosingBrace = startOfTestTwo;
int nextOpeningBrace;
do {
    nextOpeningBrace = test.indexOf("{", nextClosingBrace);
    nextClosingBrace = test.indexOf("}", nextClosingBrace + 1);
} while (nextOpeningBrace != -1 && nextOpeningBrace < nextClosingBrace);

String content = test.substring(startOfTestTwo + 1, nextClosingBrace);
```

**Update** for multi-level-nesting:

```
String test = """
 test_one{ My Text One }
 test_two{ My Text Two 
   sub_test_one{ My Sub Text 
     sub_sub_test_one{ 
        My Sub Text 
          sub_sub_sub_test_one{ My Sub Text }
     } 
   }
   sub_test_two{ My Sub Text } 
} 
test_three{ My Text Three }""";

String testTwoLabel = "test_two";
int startOfTestTwoLabel = test.indexOf(testTwoLabel);
int startOfTestTwo = test.indexOf("{", startOfTestTwoLabel);
int closingBrace = -1;
int numOfOpenBraces = 1;
int pos = startOfTestTwo + 1;
final int len = test.length();
while (pos < len && numOfOpenBraces > 0) {
    int ch = test.charAt(pos);
    switch (ch) {
        case '{': numOfOpenBraces++; break;
        case '}': 
            numOfOpenBraces--;
            closingBrace = pos;
            break;
    }
    pos++;
}
String content = test.substring(startOfTestTwo + 1, closingBrace);
```

Comment: It works! but if there are more brackets under the brackets, it does not work.
ex:
                String test = """
    test_one{
     My Text One
    }
    test_two{
     My Text Two
       sub_test_one{
         My Sub Text
           sub_sub_test_one{
         My Sub Text
           sub_sub_sub_test_one{
         My Sub Text
        }
        }
        }
       sub_test_two{
         My Sub Text
        }
    }
    test_three{
     My Text Three
    }""";

Comment: You're right, it's for single level nesting. For multi-level nesting you'd need to count the brackets (or use a stack).

Comment: I updated my answer for multi-level-nesting.